# How to restrict AWS CodeBuild to code changes only for PR update webhook

Tags: bitbucket, aws-codebuild

We have integrated our repository on Bitbucket with the AWS Codebuild service, where we have a dedicated project for handling pull requests (triggering unit & e2e tests etc).

We have just noticed that Bitbucket always triggers a webhook, even when we simply add approvers to our PR - this ends up with multiple jobs on CodeBuild, which is unnecessary duplication.

How can we avoid this? Is there a way to tell AWS CodeBuild to only trigger the job when there is a code change, not when someone changes the PR description or adds another approver?

We searched the web but could not find the solution which is really wired.